# Parsing string returns integers with different lengths

Tags: loops, rust

I'm trying to parse a vector of strings that are all the same length into a vector of integers (usize in this case).

When I loop through the original string containing all numbers separated by "\n", it works and returns a vector of strings that are all the same length. However, when I iterate over that Vec of Strings and parse it to a Vec of usize, the numbers change lengths.

Here's my code:

```
fn read_input() -> String { 
    let mut input = String::new();
    File::open("input.txt").unwrap().read_to_string(&mut input).unwrap();

    let test: Vec<&str> = input.split("\n").collect();   
    let test2: Vec<usize> = test.iter().map(|n| n.parse().unwrap()).collect();

    for num in test2{ 
        println!("{}", num);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Here's a sample of what it **should** look like:

```
100101000011
100101001010
111001001011
010110011110
111111010111
111000000111
101000101100
000000101100
111010001010
000000001110
011001111101
000000111010
010001000001
```

Here's a sample of how it looks like right now:

```
110110110110
10111101100
10000101100
1110001110
11000010001
1101010000
100111111111
101110010111
1101100100
1000010010
10000000011
110000010
1101000
```

NOTE: The full list has about 2000 entries, and the output is correct for the most part, but there are a few sections where the numbers get trimmed for some reason.

Comment: Your "integers" look strangely like binary. Are you sure you want to parse them as decimal ?

Comment: Not entirely sure how else I would parse them to be honest. I sort of thought that was my only option. What do you have in mind? All of them are binary.

Comment: You can do `let my_int = usize::from_str_radix(my_str, 2).unwrap();` for example. See more: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.from_str_radix

Comment: @DenysSéguret Awesome! I'll try that when I'm back at my computer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers aren't changed. They're numbers, there's no intrinsic `0` at the start: those are dependent on how you print them.

If you want them to have a padding with `0`, change the print call:

```
for num in test2{ 
    println!("{:012}", num);
}
```

In your case, the numbers are parsed from binary and should be printed as binary. So you want

```
for num in test2{ 
    println!("{:012b}", num);
}
```

[fmt reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/)